# Is it possible to use ng-include without web server?

Tags: angularjs

I'm running an AngularJS app which merely include a file

```
<div ng-include src="'sample.html'"></div>
```

That works when run under web server. But if the web app is run from merely double clicking from file explorer (i.e. not from web server), it doesn't include the file

Does ng-include works outside of web server? I checked the Network status on Chrome, it says **OPTIONS** on Method, and **Load cancelled** on Status

Comment: I don't think it is about web server. I think it is more like Cross-Origin issue.

Answer (score 32):

One workaround is to inline your templates:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="sample.html">
  <div>This is my sample template</div>
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/pLPL4/).

This puts your template into Angular's template cache.  When an ng-include directive is processed, Angular checks the cache first.

Comment: Is it possible to have a src attribute to the script and point to an external html file?

Comment: @Vishnu, no.  See [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script) -- there is no `src` parameter.

Comment: @MarkRajcok Your answer is something I was searching for last few days :). Thank you so much!

Comment: Note: this has to go within the element with the `ng-app` on it, I believe.

Answer (score 22):

The problem is because of `file://` protocol. Mostly all browsers disallow XHR requests when file is been served from `file://`. That is why AJAX requests are failing. And `ng-include` use them to download files.

You can launch Chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files` parameter to disable checks for `file://`.

FireFox should load files if they are in same folder (check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file%3a_URIs) for more info).

But personally prefer to start simplest NodeJS script to serve files, that could be found at [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/scripts/web-server.js) project. It require just `node` binary and gives a feeling of a normal web server.

Comment: This is indeed true! I am able to run the webpage successfully in Firefox but not in Chrome! Thank you so much for the explanation.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by running a simple nodejs server to serve static files - [http-server](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server). Make sure you have [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.36/node-v0.10.36.pkg) installed, then:

Install:

`$ sudo npm install http-server -g`

Then from your project directory:

`$ http-server`

Now you can access your files from:

`localhost:8080/whatever-file-you-have-in-your-directory.html`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Grunt along with the [grunt-html plug](https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js) to precompile your templates along with your Angular code.

Answer (score -3):

Using **virtual Host on your xampp** is the best solution , and give custom name like yourProject.dev

update **httpd-vhosts** file in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName  yourProject.dev
        ServerAlias www.yourProject.dev  yourProject.com www.yourProject.com
        DocumentRoot "C:\Users\customFolder/yourProject"
        <Directory "C:\Users\customFolder/yourProject">
            DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
            ServerSignature Off
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks IncludesNoExec
            AllowOverride All
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

then update your hosts file to `127.0.0.1 yourProject.dev`

in Windows : `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`

in Mac : `/private/etc/hosts`

**don't forget to rest your xampp/wampp**

Comment: xampp is a web server. Question asked here not to use any web sever.