# AngularJS ng-include doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive

Here is a source of the `main.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module ('myApp',[]);
        myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope){
            $scope.name = "Tim";
            $scope.partialStuff = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
            alert(window.angular.version.full);//1.3.14 is displayed
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
            {{name}}
        <div ng-repeat="partialVar in partialStuff">
            Hello: <div ng-include src="'part.html'"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also there is a `part.html`  that contains a plain text `'part'` - just several symbols.

Both files `main.html` and `part.html` are located in the same folder.

When I open `main.html` in the browser, I don't see three repeats of the content from `part.html` however I see three `Hello:`. Seems like `part.html` is not loaded.

Why?

Thank you.

**Please place it within the body tag to make it work**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="part.html">
  part
</script>
```

Comment: What's coming up in your network tab, I'm assuming it couldn't load the file? Your app probably has the wrong directory set up.

Comment: any console errors ? if no errors check the network and see whether the templates are loading correctly

Comment: Use fiddler to see what the request is doing.

Comment: Nope, no errors. The file part.html is not loaded.  (that's in Google Chrome). FF - works fine. The solution is found (please see my comment below). Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot import local files directly using the file:// protocol.

You should take a look at:
[Is it possible to use ng-include without web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420337/is-it-possible-to-use-ng-include-without-web-server)

Comment: Actually, you can, but not in every browser. IE and Chrome are the problem ones.

Comment: Yes. And I've just checked - it works in FF. The question appeared when worked with a Google Chrome.
The solution found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420337/is-it-possible-to-use-ng-include-without-web-server

Answer (score 15):

```
<div ng-include="'part.html'"></div>
```

should be the correct syntax I believe.
More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_includes.asp)

EDIT: also, the file path should be from the root and not relative of the `html` file.

Comment: I don't think there should be a double quote followed by a single quote.  Use one or the other.

Comment: @Scottie yes there should when url is string

Comment: Is the path relative to the root folder and not the html file?

Comment: <div ng-include src=... is not supported but operational syntax.

Comment: I am having a similar issue when I inspect the code I see                 <!-- ngInclude: 'features/common/fields/basicFeatureHeader.html' -->
                <!-- ngInclude: 'features/common/fields/basicFeatureFilter.html' -->
                <!-- ngInclude: 'features/common/fields/basicFeatureResultsGrid.html' -->  but the html is not rendering

Comment: Thanks, this quotes thing I forget every time.

Answer (score 0):

ng-include can be used as:

```
<div>
    <ng-include src="demo.html"></ng-include>
```

This will surely include your files like a normal src. ng-include work on local server also.There is no need to put extra server like tomcat to run this file.
This will run simply like a html file.