# how to add multiple html pages into one single html page using angularJs

Tags: html, angularjs

I created header.html, footer.html, leftpanel.html and content.html, i want to create a single html page for displaying all the header, footer, leftpanel and content pages into one page using angularjs. Is it possible?

Here is my code:

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fullcalendar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="prettyPhoto.css.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="rateit.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.cleditor.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="daterangepicker-bs3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-switch.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="widgets.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dropzone.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="validationEngine.jquery.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.gritter.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.easy-pie-chart.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="rating_style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.tablesorter.style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css">
<link href="form.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="all.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="font-awesome.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="default.js"></script>
<script src="bottom.js"></script>
<script src="topRight.js"></script>
<script src="top.js"></script>
<script src="filter.js"></script>
<script src="custom.js"></script>
<script src="charts.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="common.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-view="">

  <div class="container" ng-controller="RouteCtrl">

    <div id="header" ng-view="">
    <div ng-include="C:/Users/testuser.SOFTTRENDS/Desktop/Angular/Login/header.html">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar" >
    <div ng-include="C:/Users/testuser.SOFTTRENDS/Desktop/Angular/Login/leftpanel.html">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    <div ng-include="C:/Users/testuser.SOFTTRENDS/Desktop/Angular/Login/content.html">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    <div ng-include="C:/Users/testuser.SOFTTRENDS/Desktop/Angular/Login/footer.html">
    </div>
    </div>      

</body>

<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider

  .when('/main.html', {
    controller: 'RouteCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'C:/Users/testuser.SOFTTRENDS/Desktop/Angular/Login/main.html'
  })
  // if not match with any route config then send to home page
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: 'C:/Users/testuser.SOFTTRENDS/Desktop/Angular/Login/login.html';
  });
});

myApp.controller('RouteCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.template = {
    "header": "C:/Users/testuser.SOFTTRENDS/Desktop/Angular/Login/header.html",
    "leftpanel": "C:/Users/testuser.SOFTTRENDS/Desktop/Angular/Login/leftpanel.html",
    "content": "C:/Users/testuser.SOFTTRENDS/Desktop/Angular/Login/content.html";
    "footer": "C:/Users/testuser.SOFTTRENDS/Desktop/Angular/Login/footer.html"; 
  };
});
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you get an error? What does it look like?
And by the way: this looks like including-armageddon to me ;-)

Comment: Many things don't work properly with local file URLs. Use some simple web server on localhost to serve your pages.

Comment: @Stephan Weinhold- It is not showing any error, but i want to know without using server is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use ng-include without web server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420337/is-it-possible-to-use-ng-include-without-web-server)

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because most browsers block XHR-requests beginning with `file://`.
You can try inlining your templates as Mark Rajcok suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14420730/3218828):

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="sample.html">
    <div>This is my sample template</div>
</script>
```