# ng-include in angularjs is not working with file:/// url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

When I tried to execute an ng-include example, I am getting an error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/asdi/Desktop/myTable.htm.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

myTable.htm

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
<td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
  <div ng-include="'myTable.htm'"></div>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
          $scope.names = [{'Name':'Jhon'}, {'Name':'Charless'}, {'Name':'Nicheal'}, {'Name':'Symon'}]
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now how this will work in a cordova mobile app?

Should we always use a local http server to demo/test/develop angularjs?

Should we always launch the chrome to ignore cross origin, which is unsecured?

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420337/is-it-possible-to-use-ng-include-without-web-server

Comment: *"Should we always use a local http server to demo/test/develop angularjs?"* - **yep**