# AngularJs ng-include src ="sample.html " not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, infowindow, angularjs-ng-include

I place my html inside script as mentioned in below mentioned link :-

[Is it possible to use ng-include without web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420337/is-it-possible-to-use-ng-include-without-web-server)

like :-

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="infowindow.html">
  <h4>{{data[0]}},{{data[1]}}</h4>
 <button ng-click="test()">click</button>
</script>
```

But when i am trying to put this html inside me content so as to show infowindow on marker click it won't loading the tamplate.

here is my code :-

```js
app
  .factory(
    'Map',
    function($rootScope, $compile) {

      var canvas = document.getElementById('map'),
        defaults = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
          zoom: 4,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

      return {
        init: function(map_data, scope) {

          var user_data = map_data.user.defaults,
            locations = map_data.locations,
            map_opts = {
              "center": (typeof user_data.center !== 'undefined') ? new google.maps.LatLng(
                user_data.center[0],
                user_data.center[1]) : defaults.center,
              "zoom": (typeof user_data.zoom !== 'undefined') ? parseInt(
                user_data.zoom, 10) : defaults.zoom,
              "mapTypeId": defaults.mapTypeId
            };
         
          var Map = $rootScope.map = new google.maps.Map(
            canvas, map_opts);
          scope.markers = [];

          for (var count = locations.length, i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            var latLng = locations[i],
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(
                  latLng[0], latLng[1]),
                map: Map,
                title: '(' + latLng[0] + "," + latLng[1] + ')'
              }),
              infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            scope.markers[i] = {};
            scope.markers[i].locations = [latLng[0],
              latLng[1]
            ];

            var content = '<div id="infowindow_content" ng-include ="\'infowindow.html\'"></div>';
            var compiled = $compile(content)(scope);
            google.maps.event
              .addListener(
                marker,
                'click', (function(marker, scope,
                  compiled, localLatLng) {
                  return function() {
                    scope.data = localLatLng;
                    scope.test = test;
                    scope.$apply();
                    infowindow
                      .setContent(compiled[0].innerHTML);
                    infowindow.open(Map,
                      marker);
                  };
                })
                (
                  marker,
                  scope,
                  compiled,
                  scope.markers[i].locations));

          }
        }
      };

    });
```

I even tried with ng-include src ="'infowindow.html'"

Any Help will be appreciated ,
Thanks

Comment: if template is in separate file and you are not running in on web server it may be cross site scripting issue. Could you confirm if there are any errors on browser console?

Comment: Hey  A.J, thanks for your reply but i am runing it on my device as ionic application.and i am not getting any sort of error on browser.

Comment: try making ng-include src ="infowindow.html" to ng-include src =" 'infowindow.html' "

Comment: @A.J , yes i am getting this error in console :- file:///android_asset/www/infowindow.html Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: so , i just tried with var content = '<div id="infowindow_content" ng-include src="\'templates/infowindow.html\'"></div>';

Comment: Hey John , yes i tried with that too but still not working,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can run the snippet bellow.

Two things, when using `ng-include` you need to pass an expression of `src="infowidnow.html"` you need to pass `src="'infowindow.html'"`. This is because it is possible to use a variable which contrains the template string name.

I have included a working snippet, though I suggest you look at the Component Pattern and **NOT USE ng-include**.

As well, instead of using a `factory` and binding to `id="map"` you should use a Component or Directive and just declarativley bind to your HTML views. Right now it looks like you are fighting against AngularJS.

```js
function ButtonController() {
  this.data = ["Foo", "Bar"]
}
ButtonController.prototype.test = function() {
  alert('Test Clicked');
}

angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ButtonController', ButtonController);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  
  <div ng-controller="ButtonController as vm" ng-include src="'infowindow.html'"></div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="infowindow.html">
     <h4>{{vm.data[0]}},{{vm.data[1]}}</h4>
     <button ng-click="vm.test()">click</button>
  </script>
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, Martin thanks for your idea, i will definatily do R&D on this , as i am very much new to angularjs.I am just learning it slowly slowly.It would be my great help if you can tell me how t do this . and handle individual clicks of marker infowindow button click,Thank you.