# ng-include not including page in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here I have checked many questions for the same I tried but no luck. I am simply including ng-include in my html page but it is not adding that page in my code.

this my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head 
         content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion</title>    
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
<!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>


    <header class="jumbotron">

        <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-header">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                    <h1>Ristorante con Fusion</h1>
                    <p style="padding:40px;"></p>
                    <p>We take inspiration from the World's best cuisines, and create
                     a unique fusion experience. Our lipsmacking creations will 
                     tickle your culinary senses!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
                <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

   <!--<div ng-include src="'contactUs.html'"></div>-->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="contactUs.html">
```

```
    <footer class="row-footer">

    </footer>

<!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

</body>

</html>
```

here's my app.js

```
angular.module('confusionApp', []);
```

controller.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('confusionApp')

        .controller('MenuController', ['$scope','menuFactory', function($scope,menuFactory) {

            $scope.tab = 1;
            $scope.filtText = '';
            $scope.showDetails = false;

            $scope.dishes=menuFactory.getDishes();

            $scope.select = function(setTab) {
                $scope.tab = setTab;

                if (setTab === 2) {
                    $scope.filtText = "appetizer";
                }
                else if (setTab === 3) {
                    $scope.filtText = "mains";
                }
                else if (setTab === 4) {
                    $scope.filtText = "dessert";
                }
                else {
                    $scope.filtText = "";
                }
            };

            $scope.isSelected = function (checkTab) {
                return ($scope.tab === checkTab);
            };

            $scope.toggleDetails = function() {
                $scope.showDetails = !$scope.showDetails;
            };
        }])

        .controller('ContactController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            $scope.feedback = {mychannel:"", firstName:"", lastName:"", agree:false, email:"" };

            var channels = [{value:"tel", label:"Tel."}, {value:"Email",label:"Email"}];

            $scope.channels = channels;
            $scope.invalidChannelSelection = false;

        }])

        .controller('FeedbackController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            $scope.sendFeedback = function() {

                console.log($scope.feedback);

                if ($scope.feedback.agree && ($scope.feedback.mychannel == "")) {
                    $scope.invalidChannelSelection = true;
                    console.log('incorrect');
                }
                else {
                    $scope.invalidChannelSelection = false;
                    $scope.feedback = {mychannel:"", firstName:"", lastName:"", agree:false, email:"" };
                    $scope.feedback.mychannel="";
                    $scope.feedbackForm.$setPristine();
                    console.log($scope.feedback);
                }
            };
        }])

        .controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope','menuFactory', function($scope,menuFactory) {

             $scope.dish= menuFactory.getDish(parseInt($routeParams.id,10));

        }])

        .controller('DishCommentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            //Step 1: Create a JavaScript object to hold the comment from the form
            var stars=[{value:"1"
                       },
                       {
                         value:"2"
                       },
                       {
                         value:"3"
                       },
                       {
                         value:"4"
                       },
                       {
                           value:"5"

                       }

                        ];

            $scope.isSelected=function(checkStar){
                console.log(checkStar==5);
                return checkStar==5;
            };

            $scope.stars=stars;

            $scope.comment={name:"",rating:"5",textComments:"",date:""};

            $scope.submitComment = function () {



            }
        }])

;
```

service.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('confusionApp')
    .service('menuFactory',function(){

           var dishes=[
                         {
                          _id=0,
                          name:'Uthapizza',
                          image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                          category: 'mains',
                           label:'Hot',
                          price:'4.99',
                          description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }                                                          ]
                        },
                        {
                             _id=1,
                          name:'Zucchipakoda',
                           image: 'images/zucchipakoda.png',
                          category: 'appetizer',
                           label:'',
                          price:'1.99',
                          description:'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
                          comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }                                                          ]
                        },
                        {
                         _id=2,
                          name:'Vadonut',
                           image: 'images/vadonut.png',
                          category: 'appetizer',
                           label:'New',
                          price:'1.99',
                          description:'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }
                                                          ]
                        },
                        {
                         _id=3
                          name:'ElaiCheese Cake',
                           image: 'images/elaicheesecake.png',
                          category: 'dessert',
                           label:'',
                          price:'2.99',
                          description:'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }                                                          ]
                        }
                        ];

        this.getDishes = function(){
                                        return dishes;
                                    };
                    this.getDish = function (index) {
                                        return dishes[index];
                };

    }
);
```

Comment: are you running the application on a server ? or just static pages?

Comment: normal static pages

Answer (score 0):

`ng-include` would not work without a web-server to serve your application, as some browsers would restrict the template from loading due to `Cross Origin` issues or due to the `file://` protocol.

As per documentation:

> In addition, the browser's Same Origin Policy and Cross-Origin
>   Resource Sharing (CORS) policy may further restrict whether the
>   template is successfully loaded. For example, ngInclude won't work for
>   cross-domain requests on all browsers and for file:// access on some
>   browsers.

Also, look at :
[Is it possible to use ng-include without web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420337/is-it-possible-to-use-ng-include-without-web-server)

TL;DR - ng-include would not work without a web server.

P.S: as mentioned in the link, there is a workaround, you can include the template in the same html file by using:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="sample.html">
  <div>This is my sample template</div>
</script>
```

Comment: Oohh,.,thanks for explanation. so is there anyway I can just include my template and check??

Comment: Towards the end of the answer, I have mentioned a way, you can also look into the link

Comment: I added page as id  than I gotSCRIPT5022: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.11/$injector/modulerr?

Comment: Can you update your code with the changes... It may be due to some other error

Comment: did you change something in app.js, this looks like another type of error, not relevant to the changes that we made

Comment: its still same.Should I add that?

Comment: yeah, add it and also remove parts of code in the question which are not relevant

Comment: Where are you closing the script tag and where is the content for it?

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure about your directory structure. So just put your `contactUs.html` on the same level in the folder or give the full path in the src. for example

-- index.html

-- ContuctUs.html

then

```
<ng-include src="'contactUs.html'"></ng-include>
```

will work fine

But if your page is on some other path like

-- index.html

-- view

```
  -- contctUs.html
```

In this scenario you have to give the complete path in the source like

```
<ng-include src="'view/contactUs.html'"></ng-include>
```

Comment: its on same folder